# Find all common elements of an array of objects - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have data structured as follows:

```
var Items = [{"Name":"type1","Options":[1,2,5]},{"Name":"type2","Options":[1,2]},{"Name":"type1","Options":[2,5]}];
```

I am fairly new to javascript but I'm trying to figure out the common options associated with each name type.

The number of elements in the Items array is arbitrary. So I could have 40 for example.

My expected output for the above data would be

```
CommonOptions = [{"Name":"type1","Options":[2,5]},{"Name":"type2","Options":[1,2]}];
```

because 2 and 5 are common to all elements with name type1 and 1,2 are common to all elements with elements with name type2. I don't know how to access the data correctly.

Here is where I am up to. If someone could steer me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

```js
var Items = [{
  "Name": "type1",
  "Options": [1, 2, 5]
}, {
  "Name": "type2",
  "Options": [1, 2]
}, {
  "Name": "type1",
  "Options": [2, 5]
}];
//Define the Common Options Array as the first options and associated name
var CommonOptions = [];
CommonOptions.push(Items[0]);

//the first item is already in the common options array so start at 1
for (var i = 1, iLen = Items.length - 1; i < iLen; i++) {
  for (var j = 0, cLen = CommonOptions.length; j < cLen; j++) {

    //add all unique by name options to common options array
    if (CommonOptions[j].Name.indexOf(Items[i].Name) === -1) {
      //item name is not in the common options array
      //add item to common options array
      CommonOptions.push(Items[i]);
    } else {
      //item name is in the common options array
      // if it is in the common options array then check each Option in the Option array against the common options of that name
      //CommonOptions[j].Options.indexOf(Items[i].Options)===-1
    }
  }
}
console.log(CommonOptions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a hash table for same named objects and filter `Options` for common elements.

```js
var items = [{ Name: "type1", Options: [1, 2, 5] }, { Name: "type2", Options: [1, 2] }, { Name: "type1", Options: [2, 5] }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    common = items.reduce(function (r, o) {
        if (hash[o.Name]) {
            hash[o.Name].Options = hash[o.Name].Options.filter(function (v) {
                return o.Options.indexOf(v) !== -1;
            });
        } else {
            hash[o.Name] = { Name: o.Name, Options: o.Options.slice() };
            r.push(hash[o.Name]);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(common);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep separate the current state of the array for each name, and further filter it as that name is encountered.

```js
const Items = [{"Name":"type1","Options":[1,2,5]},{"Name":"type2","Options":[1,2]},{"Name":"type1","Options":[2,5]}];

const m = Items.reduce((m, o) => {
  const a = m.get(o.Name);
  return m.set(o.Name, a ? a.filter(n => o.Options.includes(n)) : o.Options);
}, new Map());

const res = Array.from(m.entries(), ([Name, Options]) => ({Name, Options}));
console.log(res);
```